# Unable to iterate elements using elements in nightwatch

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am trying to iterate through elements, I have tried several things pointed out in many spaces. Here is my code

```
printTotalPriceInEachCard: function(client) {
    client.elements('css selector','.price-container',function(result){
        result.value.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        })
    });
}
```

When I call this function nightwatch does not identify elements function

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined
>       at Object.pageAction.printTotalPriceInEachCard (/Users/shjain/NightsWatch/pageobjects/searchListPage.js:16:15)

I am not sure if this is incorrect way of calling elements.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have build a function in a page object that has the client object as parameter. Now I do not know how you call your function, but I would assume you call it without the client object as parameter. Now 'client' is undefined inside the function and that is what the error tells you.

But you do not need to give a function in a page object the client object. It has it already! You can access it with `this.api`.

So you can build your function like this:

```
printTotalPriceInEachCard: function() {
   this.api.elements('css selector','.price-container',function(result){
        result.value.forEach(function(element){
            console.log(element);
        })
    });
}
```